# Read values from an Excel File using Apache POI API

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using a program to read values from an excel file and then return the read values. I have tried using an iterator as well as a for loop but the program does not return all the values in the worksheet. Please suggest.

```
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Iterator;
 import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue;
    import java.io.File;

    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

    public class ExcelReading {

public static STring ReadExcel(String Path){
    String FakeReturn = null;
try
    {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(Path));

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        for(Row row:sheet)
       {
            Cell cell=row.getCell(0);
            Cell testcell = row.getCell(1);
           if(cell.getStringCellValue()!=null)
             return testcell.getStringCellValue();
           else
              break;

        }
       file.close();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("The code carries an exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return FakeReturn;
    }

 return FakeReturn;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you really think this code will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You exit as soon as you encounter a single specific cell value hence you would always get a single same result all the time.

To exhaustively traverse the sheet, while iterating over the `rows`, you would have to get a handle on the `Iterator` of the cells within that row. Once you get a handle on a single `Cell` instance, store it's value to a [Java Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/) rather than just 1 single value.

```
 Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

 while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();

    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            cell.getStringCellValue(); //Do something useful with me
...
```

**EDIT:**
To get a particular column, use `CellReference`, below:

```
XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("A11");
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
if (row != null) {
    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol());
}
```

Comment: Is there a way through which I can read the values of a particular column in the spreadsheet?

Comment: @user2911856 take a look at the edit, you can user CellReference to get a handle on a particular column